# (PHP) Rendering a different data type from database

Tags: php, mysql

I have user's data stored as an integer, but want to display it as text e.g.
user's score (stored in the database) is 2.5, but I want it to be displayed on the webpage as "Good" because "Good" will be >=2 and <3.

Comment: If there's "Good" there must also be "Bad" and perhaps other qualification. What integer values do they have? B.t.w. an integer is a whole number.

Comment: So the groupings I want are:
>=0 and <1
>=1 and <2
>=2 and <3

Well now I look silly not knowing integers have to be whole numbers! I'll go read up on datatypes and see what I need instead.

Comment: show us the code please.

Comment: And to which group belong numbers < 0 and >= 3?

Comment: I'm not having it go under 0 or above 3

Comment: Sounds like you should probably read up about `switch` statements

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you're using floating point numbers in your database, and the range is 0.0 to 3.0 I would use a simple if statement like this:

```
$score = retrieveFromDatabase();
if ($score < 1.0) {
     echo 'Bad';
} elseif ($score < 2.0) {
     echo 'Average';
} else {
     echo 'Good';
}
```

For an explanation see: [if/ifelse](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.elseif.php)